# Why did Saito age?

Tags: inception

I just watched *Inception*, and am very confused about this point. **This whole question is a spoiler and could probably all be spoiler-tagged**, so don't read it if you haven't seen the movie unless you want the plot ruined.

The plot, to my understanding, goes like this:

The team goes into Yusuf's dream, then goes into Fischer's dream inside that one, then goes further, into someone else's dream (not sure whose, but it's not really relevant right here) and then later into Limbo.

At the end, Cobb finds a very old Saito in Limbo.

[image: Saito is bald and has a very wrinkled face]

Cobb apparently had been searching for years. However, Cobb doesn't look aged at all in this scene (other than some injuries).

[image: Cobb looks the same, except for some blood on his face]

Also, in the flashbacks to when Cobb and Mal were in Limbo for fifty years, they look just like they do in the flashback after they escape.

**Why was Saito so old, while Cobb and Mal didn't age in Limbo?**

Comment: Related: [Why was Saito old in Limbo?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/65255/49)

Comment: Because Saito has been in Limbo for longer than Cobb, obvs.

Comment: And Cobb and Mal most certainly did age; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_o70GrwaaU&feature=youtu.be&t=69